# In SIP INVITE, why ACK is called a transaction

Tags: sip

ACK is considered as a separated transaction when INVITE has a 200 OK response.
But a request associated with all the responses untill a final response is obtained is considered as a transaction.

How ACK request In SIP INVITE is called a transaction when there is no response for it.

Comment: I don't believe the wording is correct: ACK (for 2xx) is a REQUEST within dialog with no answer. It's not a transaction. Quickly looking at the rfc3261, I don't see where it is written that ACK for 2xx would be a transaction...

Answer (score 3):

When the UAC receives 200 OK, the client transaction is destroyed at TL.

This is done because, the TL is unaware of the above core. The above
core can be a Proxy or an UAC core.

In case of proxy, the 200 OK is forwarded whereas in case of UAC, an
ACK is generated. Now this ACK has to
create a new transaction (transaction created by INVITE had been
destroyed)at TL for its transmission, hence the ACK for 200 OK is
outside the INVITE transaction.

For other non-2xx final responses, the client transaction at TL is not
destroyed and the ACK is generated by TL.

Hence in this case, the ACK is within the transaction.